# How to: Create a playlist with full albums for which one (or more) of its contained tracks has a 5 star rating?

Tags: itunes, windows, music, script

I am looking for a tool/script/javascript to run within windows against my iTunes database that will produce a playlist of "all albums for which I have given five stars to any one song."

I can easily get a play list of my 5 star songs (been there, done that) but now I want one that pulls in the remainder of each album that has a 5 star song.  Odds are, if I liked one song, I should listen to the rest of the album again and may find others I like as well.

I saw something like this a few months ago, but can't find the site.

http://ottodestruct.com/blog/2005/itunes-javascripts/ provides some useful scripts, but not quite what I'm looking for.

Any help out there?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this can be done purely with Smart Playlists. I'll try after breakfast.

Comment: EDIT: It seems you can't. @Chuck has the right idea here I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know of a precise solution to what you're asking, but here's a possible workaround.

Create a playlist of all the songs rated 5 stars. Change the viewable columns for the playlist to show the Album Rating. Set the rating of all of the albums to 5 stars (I believe, unfortunately, that this has to be done on Windows on an album-by-album basis). Now create a new playlist for all the albums with 5 stars.

Comment: Interesting.  I did not even know about the Album Rating.  I see that on my "Favorites" playlist (4 & 5 star songs) the Album Ratings range from 3 to 5 already, but they're hollow stars.  I'll have to experiment with that a bit.

Comment: I made a Smart Playlist and set the filter as "Album Rating is 5 stars" and so far that looks like an easy step in the right direction.  As a smart playlist, I did not have to do anything album-by-album.  It took my 74 5-star songs and turned it in to 394 - so now I'll have to check if all 74 songs (and their albums, tho some are from the same album) made it to the list.

Comment: If you haven't specifically set an album's rating, iTunes averages the ratings for the songs you've rated on the album to determine the album rating. So if half the tracks are three stars and half are five stars, iTunes will rate the album at 4 stars. When an album has such a rating, the stars will be hollow, and filled in when you override this default rating.

Comment: Got it.  I was just noticing that I have one 15 track album with 2x 5-star and 1x 3-star, but the overall album rating is 4 stars; that meshes well with the averaging idea.  Now I have to decide if I want to override that, or keep looking for another way to flesh out the "albums with 5 star songs" play list.